# Error 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor' al postear objeto desde formulario con ThymeLeaf y Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Esta es mi clase **FisicHost.java** :

// Le quite imports y getter/setters para hacerla más corta

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class FisicHost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Datacenter datacenter;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fisicHost")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Credential> credentials;

    private String name;
    private String ip;
    private String operatingSystem;
    private String notes;

    public FisicHost(){

    }

    public FisicHost(Long id, Datacenter datacenter, List<Credential> credentials, String name, String ip, String operatingSystem, String notes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.datacenter = datacenter;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.name = name;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase **Datacenter.java**:

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class Datacenter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "datacenter")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<FisicHost> fisicHostList;

    public Datacenter(){

    }

    public Datacenter(int id, String name, List<FisicHost> fisicHostList) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.fisicHostList = fisicHostList;
    }
}
```

Este es mi formulario para agregar FisicHost's a un Datacenter ...

```
        <form action="/hostFisicos" method="post" th:object="${fisicHost}">

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" th:field="*{name}" class="form-group" required="required"/>
            </div>

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="ip">Ip</label>
                <input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" th:field="*{ip}" class="form-group" required="required"/>
            </div>

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="sistemaOperativo">Sistema Operativo</label>
                <select type="text" name="sistemaOperativo" id="sistemaOperativo" th:field="*{operatingSystem}" class="form-group">
                    <option value="Windows">Windows</option>
                    <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="datacenter">Datacenter</label>
                <select type="text" name="datacenter" id="datacenter" th:field="*{datacenter}" class="form-group">
                    <option th:each="datacenter : ${allDatacenters}" th:text="${datacenter.name}" th:value="${datacenter}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!--<p th:field="*{datacenter}" th:each="datacenter : ${allDatacenters}" th:text="${datacenter.name}" th:value="${datacenter}"></p>-->

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="notas">Notas</label>
                <textarea name="notas" id="notas" th:field="*{notes}" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-group"></textarea>
            </div>

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">AGREGAR</button>
        </form>
```

Bien ... esto andaba bien hasta que se me ocurrió meter un `<select>` con la lista de los Datacenter para que el usuario pueda elegir a que Datacenter quiere agregar ese FisicHost ...

Más precisamente esto sucede en este bloque de código del template:

```
   <div class="form-control">
                <label for="datacenter">Datacenter</label>
                <select type="text" name="datacenter" id="datacenter" th:field="*{datacenter}" class="form-group">
                    <option th:each="datacenter : ${allDatacenters}" th:text="${datacenter.name}" th:value="${datacenter}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

La idea, para que se entienda mejor es hacer algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero con el código que hasta ahora les compartí me sale este error al hacer el submit del formulario

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Validation failed for object='fisicHost'. Error count: 1

Entonces googleando un poco me encontré con que tengo que hacer unas cosas extrañas para formatear el Datacenter .... y siguiendo este [tutorial](https://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/binding-nested-objects-complex-properties-with-springs-formselect-tag/) a mi modelo le agregué esta clase:

**DatacenterFormatter.java**:

```
@Component
public class DatacenterFormatter implements Formatter<Datacenter> {

    @Autowired
    DatacenterService datacenterService;

    @Override
    public Datacenter parse(String name, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return datacenterService.getDatacenterByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Datacenter datacenter, Locale locale) {
        return datacenter.getName();
    }
}
```

y mi controlador pasó a quedar así:

```
// Metodo que recibe el POST del formulario y guarda el Objeto en BD
@RequestMapping(value = "/hostFisicos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String guardarHostFisico(@ModelAttribute("fisicHost") @Valid FisicHost fisicHost){
    fisicHostService.save(fisicHost);
    return "redirect:/hostFisicos";
}
```

pero al hacer el submit sigo teniendo un error, esta vez por consola, que dice lo siguiente:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.amco.Datacenter.model.Datacenter. Expected: class
>   java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String

Entiendo que está esperando un Integer y le estoy mandando un String, pero no tengo ni la más remota idea de por donde puede venir el error ....

Alguien con experiencia que me pueda orientar o dar una mano ?

Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

dejo la solución para cualquier que lea esto en un futuro ...

La misma era MUY facil:

```
@Override
public Datacenter parse(String name, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(name);
    return datacenterService.getDatacenterById(id);
}
```

había que parsear a int el String de la interfaz ...